# Mobile number validation pattern in PHP

Tags: php

I am unable to write the exact pattern for 10 digit mobile number (as 1234567890 format) in PHP . email validation is working.

here is the code:

```
function validate_email($email)
{
return eregi("^[_\.0-9a-zA-Z-]+@([0-9a-zA-Z][0-9a-zA-Z-]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]    {2,6}$", $email);
}

function validate_mobile($mobile)
{
  return eregi("/^[0-9]*$/", $mobile);
}
```

Comment: `eregi` is deprecated. Use `preg_match`

Comment: Please note that PHP's `eregi()` function is deprecated (and has been removed entirely from recent versions). You should stop using it and switch to the `preg_match()` function instead.

Comment: When you say "10 digit mobile number", I assume you're referring specifically to mobile numbers within a certain country? If you want a regex that matches numbers for your country, you should specify what country you are in, as the pattern will differ in different countries.

Comment: A word of advice: Be generous with phone number input. Allow people to insert dashes or dots, parentheses and spaces. When validating, remove those extra characters and check if the remaining string consists of the right amount of numbers. If you allows country codes, allow adding a `+` or `00` in front, and take into account that this may change the rules for the rest of the number (removing the leading 0, for instance).

Comment: I replace eregi with preg_match , then it is showing 500 internal error

Comment: @sanzuu: It's not a simple case of replace the function name. The syntax is different between the two. There are lots of examples both on SO and elsewhere on the web that explain how to do the conversion. It's not a complicated change, but it is more than just swapping out the function name.

Comment: @Simba : it is working. email validation with eregi() and mobile validation with preg_match(). is there any problem with "eregi" in future?

Comment: @sanzuu: "is there any problem with eregi in the future?" **YES THERE IS.** See [the manual page](http://php.net/eregi). It states: *Warning This function was DEPRECATED in PHP 5.3.0, and REMOVED in PHP 7.0.0.*

Comment: @Simba : You are 100% right. I have to replace now.

Comment: (by the way -- what version of PHP are you using? If you're on 5.3 or later, you should have been getting deprecation notices already when calling eregi. And if you're not on 5.3 yet... OMG! You need to upgrade)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

**Mobile Number Validation**

You can `preg_match()` to validate 10-digit mobile numbers:

```
preg_match('/^[0-9]{10}+$/', $mobile)
```

To call it in a function:

```
function validate_mobile($mobile)
{
    return preg_match('/^[0-9]{10}+$/', $mobile);
}
```

**Email Validation**

You can use `filter_var()` with `FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL` to validate emails:

```
$email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
  $emailErr = "Invalid email format"; 
}
```

To call it in a function:

```
function validate_email($email)
{
    return filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
}
```

However, `filter_var` will return filtered value on success and `false` on failure.

More information at http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_form_url_email.asp.

**Alternatively**, you can also use `preg_match()` for email, the pattern is below:

```
preg_match('/^[A-z0-9_\-]+[@][A-z0-9_\-]+([.][A-z0-9_\-]+)+[A-z.]{2,4}$/', $email)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this regex below to validate a mobile phone number.

```
\+ Require a + (plus signal) before the number
[0-9]{2} is requiring two numeric digits before the next
[0-9]{10} ten digits at the end.
/s Ignores whitespace and break rows.

$pattern = '/\+[0-9]{2}+[0-9]{10}/s';

OR for you it could be:

$pattern = '/[0-9]{10}/s';

If your input text won't have break rows or whitespaces you can simply remove the 's' at the end of our regex, and it will be like this:

$pattern = '/[0-9]{10}/';
```

Answer (score 2):

**For India** : *All mobile numbers in India start with 9, 8, 7 or 6 which is based on GSM, WCDMA and LTE technologies.*

```
function validate_mobile($mobile)
{
    return preg_match('/^[6-9]\d{9}$/', $mobile);
}

if(validate_mobile(6428232817)){
    echo "Yes";
}else{
    echo "No";
}
```

// Output will Yes

Answer (score 0):

For any mobile number including country code, to check if valid or not simply use

```
filter_var($mobilevariable, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUM_INT);
```

do this within a function and call `function name($mobilevariable)`.  Here, + sign will be accepted, ie any country code.  No need for `preg_match` or `preg_match_all()`